# Change Power Plan silently with Run

Tags: windows, power-management, rundll32.exe

Googled all around with no answers.
I want to change my laptop's Power Scheme silently. I used to run

```
powercfg.exe /SetActive <GUID>
```

Yet this creates a console window that flashes quickly. I don't want it to show so I'm looking for an approach like

```
rundll32.exe some.dll,someFunction someArgs
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Hide your Window with a Scheduled Task

Create a Scheduled Task to run your command but configure the task to run in the context of the SYSTEM user account.  When the task runs it won't be in your user session and therefore any windows opened won't be visible to you.

To do this, create the task, then on the *General* tab of the task's properties, configure the option **When running the task, user the following user account** to use the `SYSTEM` account.  Do not let the task run with your own user account, otherwise you'll still see the console window flash.

You can then either run the task On Demand, or schedule it to run when desired.

Comment: If hiding the window had solved my problem, I wouldn't have posted it. In fact I know how to hide any window with VBScript, but that's not what I want.